# How to fix Import error in Visual studio code in window 8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

When I try to import  pygame in visual studio code.

The following error is shown by visual studio code:

Import Error: DLL load failed while importing pywintypes: The specified procedures could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**
Pyinstaller requires both pypiwin32 and pywin32 to be installed. Please double check that you have both the packages installed by entering the following into the command prompt:

`pip install pywin32`

`pip install pypiwin32`

**Additional Links / References:**
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1840

Comment: No Problem, Happy to help! If you don't mind, please mark this as the best answer, I am trying to increase my reputation, thanks!